# Erlang parse multiple parameters

Tags: erlang

I have a simple record

```
#client{level}
```

level can be : user / superUser / manager / admin

I would like to accept to the function only when level is manager and admin.
How would shrink this into only one :

```
parse(Client = #client{level=manager}) ->
    ok;
parse(Client = #client{level=admin}) ->
    ok.
```

Or should I use Guards ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should definitely use guards:

```
parse(Client = #client{level = Level}) when Level == manager; Level == admin ->
    ok;
```

Expressiveness of pattern matching is limited to binding and comparing equality of defined values. You can't write it like in [type specification](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html):

```
-spec foo('admin' | 'manager') -> 'ok'.
```